# JMenuBar cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar, cannot-find-symbol

I have a problem where I am trying to implement a JMenuBar but keep getting a cannot find symbol error. I have the JFrame in a separate class along with the main method and the JFrame instatiates an object of the MainPanel class. What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

The full error message reads

cannot find symbol

symbol: method setJMenuBar (JMenuBar)

location: Class MainPanel

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

//Whole bunch of code

JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu archive;


public Uppgift2Panel(){

    //Whole bunch of code


    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    archive = new JMenu();
    menuBar.add(archive);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //Whole bunch of code


   }

}
```

Comment: Adding the complete error message is always better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JPanel` doesn't have a `setJMenuBar(...)` method.

You add the menubar to the frame using the `setJMenuBar(...)` method of the `JFrame`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples to get you started.

Start with the working code. The tutorial code will show you how to better structure you code. Keep the tutorial link handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: You could also add that the JMenubar is designed to be added in a `JFrame` with the `setJMenuBar(menuBar)` method.

Comment: All right thanks! I guess I'll need to implement the menu bar in the JFrame class.